# Can't compile to C on new PC with "same" old config rebuilt

Tags: compile

I am running MMA 11.0.1.0 64 bit recently migrated to this Windows 10 64 bit machine from a Windows 7 64 bit machine.

On the old machine I had Visual Studio 2015 installed, and compilation was setup in in MMA 10 but continued to work fine in 11.

On the new PC I downloaded my MMA afresh and made sure to get the 2015 community edition of visual studio I had before (though possibly with some "updates") [NB I first tried visualcppbuildtools_full.exe, as recommended by @szabolcs somewhere, but that also produced the C1083 error so I thought I;d go back to what I thought I knew... So, we're several hours into this now.]

```
Needs["CCompilerDriver`"]
Needs["CompiledFunctionTools`"]
CCompilers[Full]
```

returns

```
{{"Name" -> "Visual Studio", 
  "Compiler" -> 
   CCompilerDriver`VisualStudioCompiler`VisualStudioCompiler, 
  "CompilerInstallation" -> 
   "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0", 
  "CompilerName" -> Automatic}, {"Name" -> "Intel Compiler", 
  "Compiler" -> CCompilerDriver`IntelCompiler`IntelCompiler, 
  "CompilerInstallation" -> None, 
  "CompilerName" -> Automatic}, {"Name" -> "Generic C Compiler", 
  "Compiler" -> CCompilerDriver`GenericCCompiler`GenericCCompiler, 
  "CompilerInstallation" -> None, "CompilerName" -> Automatic}}
```

But on a simple compilation test

```
compListMul = Compile[{{l1, _Real, 1}, {l2, _Real, 1}}, l1 * l2 ,CompilationTarget -> "C", "RuntimeOptions" -> "Speed"]
```

I get

> CreateLibrary::cmperr: Compile error:
>   C:\Users\Julian\AppData\Roaming\Mathematica\ApplicationData\CCompilerDriver\BuildFolder\lotan-14584\Working-lotan-14584-14612-1\compiledFunction0.c(1):
>   fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'math.h': No such file or
>   directory
>
> Compile::nogen: A library could not be generated from the compiled
>   function.

This seems very fundamentally broken so I'm hoping the fix is straightforward...

Question: what's wrong and how do I fix it?

Many, many thanks

Comment: I am not at all confident in this, but it is possible that some components of Visual Studio are missing.  `math.h` should come with it, and it is such an essential part that I find it hard to believe that it is even possible not to install it.

Comment: @Szabolcs Well, there is one in C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.16299.0\km\crt but, whilst no expert, that location doesn't feel right... I think I may have to uninstall a lot and go back to square 1. Only things is, VS said it installed ok.

Answer (score 1):

On a different application, I ran into the same compilation problem. I was missing the Boost libraries which had somehow been removed in a new installation. Reinstalling them fixed the problem. Maybe check if they have been installed? Alternatively, try reinstalling the Microsoft 2017 build tools making sure the Cmake tools and compilers for C++ are included in installation options?

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2016/11/16/introducing-the-visual-studio-build-tools/?__hstc=268264337.630b87d4bcc78d7fe15313f9e4589741.1517510181478.1517510181478.1517510181478.1&__hssc=268264337.1.1517510181479&__hsfp=716450492

http://www.boost.org/

Comment: Boost is not needed for Mathematica's `Compile`, and neither is cmake. This problem is not related to either boost or cmake.  The 2017 build tools are not compatible with OP's version of Mathematica.

Comment: Fair enough. Not 100% sure then, but the only reasonable explanations are as you suggested which is that somehow VS 2015 is corrupted or that VC++ was forgotten to be installed on installing VS 2015 (if this is the case see solutions here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38290169/cannot-find-corecrt-h-universalcrt-includepath-is-wrong). Math.h is too core to be missing otherwise if its not a problem with supplemental libraries. Presumably reinstalling/modifying the installation or installing the Visual C++ Build Tools 2015 should solve the problem, no?

Comment: I spent some time last night trying to clean out old vs etc installations and will try from scratch again this weekend.

Comment: I used @szabolcs suggestion of the C++ build tools only. Didn't work. Installation seemed ok, and the environment variable was there for VStools but I still had the C1083 fatal error. So I thought I'd try cygwin instead. Once that was installed, MMA compiled... using visual studio - it's the only compiler return by CCompilers[] (no sign of cygwin). MMA has been restarted but the system hasn't so I have no idea what's going on, but it works now so...